# How to use i18n file in a service (angular-translate)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internationalization, angular-translate

I'm using angular-translate to translate my website and it works. But now, I want to show an error dialog when there is a problem (api request). To do that, I've created a service to display a modal with two parameters title and the error message.

One part of the error message is static, so I can translate it directly with angular-translate.

Here my service (errorModal.service.js) :

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core.project')
        .factory('errorDialog', ['$mdDialog', '$document', '$translatePartialLoader', '$translate', errorDialog]);

        /** @ngInject */
    function errorDialog($mdDialog, $document, $translatePartialLoaderProvider, $translate)
    {
        var service = {
            displayError : displayError
        };

        // path to i18n folder : /app/core-project/services/i18n/{lang}.json but it can't be used...
        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('/app/core-project/services/');

        return service;

        function displayError(title, errorMessage, clickOutsideToClose)
        {
            // error_modal.message isn't translated
            var message = $translate.instant('error_modal.message') + errorMessage;
            console.log(message); // show "error_modal.message"

            $mdDialog.show(
                $mdDialog.alert()
                    .parent(angular.element($document.body))
                    .clickOutsideToClose(clickOutsideToClose)
                    .title(title)
                    .htmlContent(message)
                    .ariaLabel(title)
                    .ok('OK')
            );
        }

    }

})();
```

How can use i18n file in a specific path in this service ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just added translatePartialLoader provider into my config, specified the folder where to find the translations.

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core.project')
        .config(config);

    /** @ngInject */
    function config($translatePartialLoaderProvider)
    {
        // Put your custom configurations here

        $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/core-project/services');
    }

})();
```

and my errorModal.service.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core.project')
        .factory('errorDialog', ['$mdDialog', '$document', '$translate', errorDialog]);

        /** @ngInject */
    function errorDialog($mdDialog, $document, $translate)
    {
        var service = {
            displayError : displayError
        };

        return service;

        function displayError(statusCode, errorMessage)
        {
            var clickOutsideToClose = false;

            var title = $translate.instant('core_project.dialog.error.status_code', { statusCode: statusCode });
            var message = $translate.instant('core_project.dialog.error.message', { message: errorMessage });

            $mdDialog.show(
                $mdDialog.alert()
                    .parent(angular.element($document.body))
                    .clickOutsideToClose(clickOutsideToClose)
                    .title(title)
                    .htmlContent(message)
                    .ariaLabel(title)
                    .ok('OK')
            );
        }

    }

})();
```